# Excel DNA Distibute with Azure possibly

Tags: c#, azure, excel-dna

I have built an Excel Add In using Excel DNA and C#. I am able to build the app thru Visual Studio 2017 by setting it to Release and build. As of now, I distribute the excel add in by going to the release folder and copying the .xll file and pasting it to the users add in path on their machines. This process works but as you can tell not really professional. In addition, I am also using Azure to host winforms applications. My question, is what is the best way to distribute and possibly install the .xll file on users machine. (The install is really copying over the previous .xll file). Can I use azure to do this (Just hold the .xll file)? Or do I need to go thru Jenkins or similar type application.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to deploy Excel-DNA add-ins is by creating an installer that gets downloaded and run by the user.

- https://github.com/Excel-DNA/WiXInstaller
- https://jiripik.com/2017/02/25/use-advanced-installer-excel-dna-project/